# Xamarin Android EditText setError Not Displaying Text

Tags: android, xamarin.android

For some reason I am not able to display error message text in my EditText. I am using Xamarin.Android 4.16.0. I have a simple use case

```
private EditText _businessNameEdit;
_businessNameEdit = _rootView.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editTextBusinessName);

    //wire up save button handler
            if (_saveButton != null) {
                _saveButton.Click += (sender, e) => {
                    validateFormInput();


void validateFormInput ()
        {
            Drawable errorIcon = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.statuserror); 

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (_businessNameEdit.Text)) {
                _businessNameEdit.Error = "Cannot be Empty";
                _businessNameEdit.RequestFocus ();
                //_businessNameEdit.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, Resource.Drawable.statuserror, 0);
            }
        }               };
```

If I do editText.Error = "Some message", the default Android error Icon will show with no message, like so and if I use SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrisicBounds() it show my custom image with with not message.

[image: Xamarin Android Edittext Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My goodness, spent the whole day to realise that it was a theme issue. Added

```
android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

to the Activity and that was it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably text color is white so try to set different color for text in Error message:

```
_businessNameEdit.Error =
                  Html.fromHtml("<font color='black'>Cannot be Empty</font>");
```

Comment: Thank you, however that still did not display anything, I added your code like this _businessNameEdit.Error = (Html.FromHtml ("<font color='black'>Cannot be Empty</font>")).ToString ();